# Google sheets addon custom function shows #NAME error until I click on menu

Tags: google-sheets, add-on

I've created an internal addon for my Google workspace for google sheets. I've created the following functions in the addon which I've deployed via marketplace and installed into google sheets:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Activate Plugin', 'helloWorldBox')
      .addToUi();
}
 
function helloWorldBox() {
  Browser.msgBox("Hello World");
}


function helloWorld() {
  return "hello world";
}
```

For some reason, when I create a new spreadsheet and to cell A1 '=helloWorld()' I get a #NAME error. However, when I click on the "Activate Plugin" menu item, then the helloWorld() function works. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I got the same error when running the custom function `helloWorld()` when the script was not yet saved, does the dialog box of the error displays to you as: `Unknown function: 'helloWorld'.`?

Comment: @GabrielCarballo yes